# Does windows 7 stop services/processes if low on ram?

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with some customers where a service is stopped (Mysql). Mysql uses a fair amount of memory and I am wondering if windows decides to stop it when low on ram.

Is there any other way to debug this?

Comment: Most applications shut down if out of memory. Either gracefully, or crash that involves screaming in a ball of flames. I doubt windows does this automatically, and I therefore think that what you're seeing is a crash of some sort. I do not know for sure hence why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows does not stop anything on its own (linux has OOMKiller but windows does not). MySQL, how ever, may die if it fails to allocate as much memory as it needs. You should do the following:

- Check event log on (it may contain information telling you why service been stopped)
- Check MySQL error log: it should have errors.
- Use Windows Performance Monitoring tools, or (even better!) enable Data Collector for several days and check bottlenecks according to these articles: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/25/an-overview-of-troubleshooting-memory-issues.aspx
- Check your MySQL configuration for amount of memory required: http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/ .

Comment: Will do these steps on the machine.